# Angular Issue in a service accessing object via method

Tags: angular

I have the following angular service which was typed after an online tutorial.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseService {
  data = {
drivers: [ 
  {
  id: 1,
  name: 'John Doe',
  email: 'john.doe@gmail.com',
  phone: '+3233 3213 321',
  city: 'Berlin',
 address: 'ALuft stasse gasdddress'
}
],

vehicles: [
  {
    id : 1,
    lp: "GOD-258",
    year:2015,
    manifacturer: "VW",
    cosumption: 7,
    engine: "diesel"
  }
],
fueling: [
  {
    id : 1,
    vehicle:1,
    driver:1,
    amount:40,
    date:"2019-04-02"

  }
],


}

  constructor() { }
  getAll(dataType: string):any[]{
 return this.data[dataType];
  }
}
```

However I got an issue with the getAll method.

"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ drivers: { id: number; name: string; email: string; phone: string; city: string; address: string; }[]; vehicles: { id: number; lp: string; year: number; manifacturer: string; cosumption: number; engine: string; }[]; fueling: { ...; }[]; }'."

What is strange for me that the isntructor in the video use the same method for accessing data object so I am clueles what could be the issue with the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [tsconfig.json documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny). You have enabled noImplicit any warning. This is the reason you are seeing this error.

Lets break down your types:

1. `this.data` is of type `{drivers: {id: number, ...}[], vehicles: {...}}`
2. Parameter `dataType: string` is of course a string
3. Accessing `this.data` with a string type will not work because a generic string is not an index type of `this.data`

In order to tackle the problem you have to do some type case or specifing your types a bit better. Here are some suggestions:

- Changing the `dataType` parameter type to the concrete wanted type

```js
getAll(dataType: keyof typeof this["data"]): any[] {
    return this.data[dataType]; // dataType is a known index of this.data
}
```

- Using an interface to reuse this type later (my prefered way)

```js
interface CarInformation {
    drivers: { id: number, name: string, ... }[]
    vehicles: {...}[]
}

class BaseService {
    getAll<T extends keyof CarInformation>(dataType: T): CarInformation[T] {
        return this.data[dataType];  // dataType is a known index of this.data (CarInformation type)
    }
}
```